# DataGridView check all Rows vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
Private Sub comboBoxStudentID_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comboBoxStudentID.SelectedIndexChanged
    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.dataGridViewStudent.Rows

        If dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString.Contains(comboBoxStudentID.Text) Then dr.Visible = True Else dr.Visible = False


    Next
End Sub
```

I've created this method to check and display a row that contains the same Student ID as selected from the comboBoxStudentID the problem is it only checks the first row of the DataGridView. How can I make it check all of the rows if there is match of Student ID?

Comment: Can you provide more information? The code looks fine how it is.

Comment: @ProGrammer when I choose Student ID 1 from the comboBoxStudentID the datagridview will display the the row containg the student id 1. But when I choose other Student ID it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you checked that the text is restricted to the ID `"2"` and not `"2 "` or something similar?

Comment: @ProGrammer can you elaborate on that thought cause I'm new to VB. How do I do that exactly? Am I missing something on my code?

Comment: Change that if statement to be multiple lines. One to hold `dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString`, another to hold `comboBoxStudentID.Text` and the third to perform the if statement. Add a breakpoint and check the values yourself.

Comment: @ProGrammer can you give me like a sample structure to follow?

Comment: @user3219333 what ProGrammer is saying is do `Dim rowValue As String = dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString` and `Dim studentId As String = comboBoxStudentID.Text` so that you can clearly identify both values. This would be handy when debugging to check your values. Then your if statement would be `If rowValue.Contains(studentId)...`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your data is organized, you could do this by binding the `DataGridView` and the `ComboBox` to the same data source. Since this is not specified and looking at the snippet of code (which appears to work) it appears to loop through the rows and if the currently selected combo box text is contained in the first column cell, then make that row visible. Otherwise make the row invisible.

The posted code appears to work however there is one scenario you may want to consider. If the combo box contains the values that are in column one of the `DataGridView`, THEN, when the user selects a value in the combo box, the `DataGridView` will display ONLY those values that match the current combo box selection. This appears to be what you are trying to do.

The problem is how do you re-display all the rows?

Once the combo box selection has changed to some value, the user can delete the selection but all the rows will not display unless you handle another event. Also this strategy is not very user intuitive. One possible solution (below) simply adds a top item of “Reset” to the top of the combo boxes items. Then when the user selects “Reset” all row will become visible. Hope this helps.

To reiterate:  you should consider setting this up with a `DataSource` and possibly a `BindingSource` where this is done for you automatically. Just a thought.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
      If (Not dr.IsNewRow) Then
        If dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString.Contains(ComboBox1.Text) Then
          dr.Visible = True
        Else
          dr.Visible = False
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Else
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
      row.Visible = True
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```